# Algorithm to spread dots evenly on a circle (Shell Model - Chemistry)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, chemistry

I want to create an illustrator script that places dots around a circle.

Let's say the shells are given, but I need a way to evenly spread out a n amount of dots (electrons) on a n-sized circle. For example 2 dots on the first circle, 8 on the second, etc.

[Here is an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3aElectron_shell_051_Antimony.svg&page=1)

To rephrase my problem: I have up to 7 circles that are all set. How do I spread out the dots on those circles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the whole circle is `2 * PI` radians, circle center is at (0, 0) and suppose you have `n` dots, you have to place the i'th dot on coordinate x = `R * cos(i * 2 * PI / n)` and y = `R * sin(i * 2 * PI / n)` for `i = 0..n-1` where `R` is the radius of current circle.

This is all about [Polar coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)

Comment: Check your maths - this would place at angles +∞, 2π, π, 2π/3, π/2, - it should by `2πi/n` not `2π/i`

Comment: This answer is wrong - it will place dots more DENSLY near the center of the circle. You shouldn't consider "random polar coordinate" when "even" distribution is required.

Comment: @enigmatoP indeed, corrected the obvious mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i =0; i < 60; i++){aDot=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];aDot.style.top = sin(i+43/9.4)*120+180;aDot.style.left= cos(i+43/9.4)*120+400;}
```

[try it here](https://plabsfill.com/game/xp/)

[Live example of full functioning circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcbMI.gif)

Comment: You're code as is very hard to read due to missing line breaks.  Please format the code properly to include line breaks between statements.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32368326)